# Notification revived but not displayed airship React Native

Tags: react-native, push-notification, notifications, android-notifications, urbanairship.com

I've been trying to get notifications by airship for my app. It worked with the iOS fine, but with Android, there are some issues.

In the first I was getting a warning whenever I send a notification saying:

> No task registered for key ReactNativeFirebaseMessagingHeadlessTask

I searched for some answer and finally I added these lines to my code:

```js
messaging()
.setBackgroundMessageHandler(async (remoteMessage) => {
      console.log('Message handled in the background!', remoteMessage);
});
```

It kind of works now but displaying the notification still doesn't work. Now when I receive the notification I get this log from the above function:

```sh
Message handled in the background!,
```

```json
{
  "data": {
    "com.urbanairship.metadata": "eyJ2ZXJzaW9uX2lkIjoxLCJ0aW1lIjoxNjM2NDcxNzk3MjgyLCJwdXNoX2lkIjoiZDczN2QxZWMtNTExNC00NWI3LThhNGYtYjI1NWNmYWZiZDcxIiwiY2FtcGFpZ25zIjp7ImNhdGVnb3JpZXMiOltdfX0=",
    "com.urbanairship.push.ALERT": "Congratulations! You've successfully configured Android Push.",
    "com.urbanairship.push.APID": "26e8cdec-3e61-437c-940d-cd9e75c3a7df",
    "com.urbanairship.push.CANONICAL_PUSH_ID": "d737d1ec-5114-45b7-8a4f-b255cfafbd71",
    "com.urbanairship.push.PUSH_ID": "e51fd020-4171-11ec-a035-02423b27e6fe"
  },
  "from": "827761845713",
  "messageId": "0:1636471797306222%14a7377ff9fd7ecd",
  "sentTime": 1636471797292,
  "ttl": 2419200
}
```

It's clearly received the notification without any error from the phone or the platform (it says sent successfully), but it still won't show up in the phone.

Answer (score -4):

The problem is located in the AndroidManifest.xml file.
I removed this and everything works now.

```
<service android:name="com.dieam.reactnativepushnotification.modules.RNPushNotificationListenerService" android:exported="false">
  <intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
  </intent-filter>
</service>
```

Comment: Not related to the problem you have mentioned here sir. Good if it works for you.